# How to authenticate and authorize a user through x.509 certificate in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, authentication, servlets, ssl

I would like to set up my webapp to support client-cert authentication.

I've configured the tomcat's connector:

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="want"  keystoreFile="***" keystorePass="***" keystoreType="JKS" port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" secure="false" sslProtocol="TLS" truststoreFile="***" truststorePass="***" truststoreType="JKS"/>
```

Web.xml config:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
    <realm-name>My APP</realm-name>
</login-config>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>restricted access datasets</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/restrictedAccess/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>restrictedDatasetUser</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint >
</security-constraint>
```

When I try to go to https://../restrictedAccess/ the browser asks for the certificate, I choose my certificate but the page is not shown because it throws this error: 403 forbiden.

I would like to do two things:

Authenticate users by myself. Get the CN, find the user details and then authenticate. My user's username is not the same as CN.

Authorize users by myself getting their grants from the DB.

Is it possible to do these two things without using Spring Security? I don't know how to authenticate by myself using servlets because I'm used to Spring Security.

Answers will be voted.

Answer (score 0):

I know, that the question was asked more than 3 years ago, but recently I encountered the same problem, so here is the possible way to resolve it:

1) First of all, you should set clientAuth to false. This way you can ask tomcat to authorize users yourself whenever you want.

2) Then in your code, in my case it was in post method of controller, you can ask tomcat to request certificate from user via this method:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.catalina.connector.Request;
import org.apache.coyote.ActionCode;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLSupport;

.........

public X509Certificate[] requestAndGetClientCertificate(
            ServletRequest servletRequest ) {
        X509Certificate[] result = new X509Certificate[0];
        try {
            // get protected org.apache.catalina.connector.Request
            // using reflection
            Field apacheRequest = servletRequest.getClass().getDeclaredField("request");
            apacheRequest.setAccessible(true);
            Request catalinaRequest = (Request) apacheRequest.get(servletRequest);
            org.apache.coyote.Request coyoteRequest = catalinaRequest.getCoyoteRequest();
            // here we invoke a browser certificate prompt window
            coyoteRequest.action(ActionCode.REQ_SSL_CERTIFICATE, null);
            result = (X509Certificate[]) coyoteRequest.getAttribute(SSLSupport.CERTIFICATE_KEY);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return result;
    }
```

You need to add catalina.jar and tomcat-coyote.jar to your classpath.

3) That method return array of X509Certificate, and the first one is the one, chosen by user. So, now you can check that certificate with your certificate from database